# WPF custom progress bar clipping

Tags: wpf, progress-bar, styles

I've created a custom progress bar as follows:

```
<!-- Custom progress bar -->
    <Style
        x:Key="CopyProgressBar"
        TargetType="ProgressBar">
        <Setter
            Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate
                    TargetType="ProgressBar">
                    <Grid>
                        <Border
                            x:Name="PART_Track"
                            CornerRadius="5"
                            BorderBrush="#BBC6C4"
                            BorderThickness="2" />
                        <Rectangle
                            x:Name="PART_Indicator"
                            Fill="#A5B2B0"
                            RadiusX="5"
                            RadiusY="5"
                            Margin="3"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Here's how it is used:

```
<ProgressBar
            x:Name="copyProgress"
            Height="13"
            Width="279"
            Canvas.Left="158"
            Canvas.Top="103"
            Minimum="0"
            Maximum="100"
            Style="{StaticResource CopyProgressBar}" />
```

It works quite well, but when the progress is full, the right side of the fill bar is clipped, which removes the rounding styling I'm going for. I've fiddled with padding, margins, max width, etc, but I can't find a way to prevent the clipping.

Here is an image:

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This was an interesting one to answer.  I finally got it nailed down to being the margin that was causing the problem.  The progress bar sets the width of PART_Indicator based on the width of PART_Track regardless of the margin or paddings that are set.  The following style will get you the desired behaviour.

```
<Style x:Key="CopyProgressBar" TargetType="ProgressBar">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ProgressBar">                  
                <Border BorderBrush="#BBC6C4" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="5" Padding="1">
                    <Grid x:Name="PART_Track" >
                        <Rectangle x:Name="PART_Indicator" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Fill="#A5B2B0" RadiusX="5" RadiusY="5"/>
                    </Grid>                  
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: Bingo. Thanks! It's not exactly an intuitive process to customize these controls. Do you know of any helpful tutorials or documentation to help with such things?

Comment: For me its always trial and error (in Kaxaml for speed).  you can use Blend to copy and alter the styles but styling as a whole is a powerful, brilliant but complex process so even this can be awkward.

Comment: +1 As a side note...you would actually want to set Padding="3" on the newly added Border to get the feel he was going for prior.

Comment: @Aaron - If you run both styles padding=3 and margin=3 give different results.  To my eyes padding=1 looks most like the expected result.